# How slow is InnoDB on large selects vs. MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I made many searches about InnoDB and MyISAM and I think I now undertstand the avantages and disavantages of each. But I'm looking for more details about a specific disavantage of InnoDB. I've read that it's great for tables with a lot of write and update, but that the select are slower on large tables (mine will be +-10 millions).

Considering that my table will handle a lot of writes and updates (+-100/second), but selects would occur way less often (only 500 times a day maximum), always selected by the `parent_id` row. I'm asking myself;

How slow is InnoDB on large tables? Can I still expect good performances on selects?

I can't find any benchmark suiting my question. Thank for your help.

Comment: It's not just about speed: InnoDB offers full [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliance, without which you will face concurrency issues if you don't lock your tables against all read operations when performing a write - this could cause considerable speed bottlenecks in MyISAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen anywhere that InnoDB are slower at big selects, but I guess it's possible, since that wasn't the highest priority.

Still, since you say your system will be write-heavy, it's clear that MyISAM would suffer heavily there, since it can only do either multiple simultaneous readers or a single writer per table.  InnoDB, on the other hand manages row-level locks, and even then, it allows multiple readers to read the previous version up to the `COMMIT` moment, where it atomically replaces the new version of the data.

A related issue is the ACID compliance.  Without these you really risk turning your data into a hopelessly inconsistent mess; particularly with big tables and lots of updates.

Finally, even if somehow you could manage MyISAM to perform better than InnoDB, that doesn't mean InnoDB is inadecuate at all.  In the extreme case, you could just put a couple of SSDs in RAID1 and it will happily handle a few thousands of updates a second.